# MTU (IPv4) tests in Linux

Tags: debian, tcpdump, nmap, icmp

I noticed I have several networks with all ICMP messages blocked at the firewall level, except for ICMP echo and reply.

I know that there is a need *at least* ICMP messages type 3 in IPv4 have to be allowed for the MTU negotiation to occur.

The packets can be sniffed with the command:

```
sudo tcpdump icmp
```

However, how do I generate ICMP packets type 3 on one remote point to make global tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need ICMP type 3 "destination unreachable" packets to provide *healthy* IP connections.

The easiest way to generate ICMP packets type 3 for testing is by using the `nping` program.

The `nping` program is part of the `nmap` package, and as such there is a need to have it installed.  For it you have to do:

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

After having it installed, to test a remote Linux system, starting running on the remote side, to listen for ICMP type 3 and 4 packets:

```
sudo tcpdump  'icmp[0] = 3'
```

or

```
sudo tcpdump  '(icmp[0] = 3) and (host ip_or_dns_of_nping_sender)'
```

and then do the other system/side to send the ICMP type 3 packets:

```
sudo nping --icmp-type 3 ip_or_dns_of_remote
```

Be sure to test them in both directions.

As an example, using the loopback interface to show the test in the local machine:

In the first terminal - listening for ICMP type 3 messages:

```
$sudo tcpdump  -i lo 'icmp[0] = 3'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:37:44.089420 IP localhost > localhost: [|icmp]
21:37:45.090092 IP localhost > localhost: [|icmp]
21:37:46.091289 IP localhost > localhost: [|icmp]
21:37:47.093095 IP localhost > localhost: [|icmp]
21:37:48.095019 IP localhost > localhost: [|icmp]
^C
5 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

In the second terminal - sending ICMP type 3 messages:

```
$sudo nping --icmp-type 3 localhost
Starting Nping 0.6.47 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2017-03-06 21:37 WET
SENT (0.0221s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable     (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
RCVD (0.2088s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable  (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
SENT (1.0228s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
RCVD (1.2088s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
SENT (2.0240s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
RCVD (2.2088s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
SENT (3.0258s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
RCVD (3.2088s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
SENT (4.0277s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 
RCVD (4.2088s) ICMP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1 Destination unreachable (type=3/code=0) ttl=64 id=40477 iplen=28 

Max rtt: 186.715ms | Min rtt: 181.081ms | Avg rtt: 184.307ms
Raw packets sent: 5 (140B) | Rcvd: 5 (140B) | Lost: 0 (0.00%)
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 4.24 seconds
```

[image: unreachable]

Comment: Source quench has been formally deprecated for half a decade because it's a specific security issue, MUST be blocked by both hosts and firewalls, and "We note that security devices such as the Snort Network Intrusion
      Detection System (NIDS) have logged ICMP Source Quench messages as
      such for more than ten years [Anderson2002]."  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6633

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks for the tip, changed the answer.